# Add value to 2sxc Global setting

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

In 2sxc module there is Global sction with Language code and status.

Is posible to add custom section with my own properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now this is not possible yet, would need extensive planing / architecture to be sure we do it the right way, so no priority as of now.